# Wallet on private chain not watching contracts?

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-deployment, out-of-gas, genesis

I set up an ethereum private chain for testing smart contracts a while back. Recently, I've been unable to deploy and interact with contracts successfully. Here is what used to work:

1) I created a chain in the command line:

```
geth --identity "testChain" --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir 
"C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop\testChain" --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi 
"db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 init C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop\customGenesis.json
```

Using this genesis:

```
{
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",     "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x0",     "gasLimit": "0x8000000",     "difficulty": "0x400",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",     "alloc": {    }
}
```

2) I run my chain:

```
geth --identity "testChain" --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir 
"C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop\testChain" --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi 
"db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 console
```

3) Start ethereum wallet/mist and it automatically connects to my 'private-net'

4) Proceed to create an account, and start mining ether through `geth attach`

5) Navigate to 'Deploy Contracts' and paste my contract code. In this example, I am using the code provided by ethereum for issuing your own token.

6) Deploy contract.

7) `Miner.start()` and watch the 12 confirmations.

8) I am now able to view the currency I've created. I can also go manage the contract, as my account is the owner. Transfer assets, etc.

When I attempt this now, I run into problems at steps 6 and 8. In step 6, I sometimes get a gas limit error. I resolve this by exiting the wallet and trying again. When the contract is successfully deployed, I watch as the confirmations are completed. The problem is that my account never shows my ownership of 'shares' as the ethereum guide says it should. I am not able to transfer any of my 'shares', and there is no place to manage the contract.

Any thoughts?